# If/Else Statement and Lists Within Functions - Python 3.x

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, if-statement

So I'm trying to design two functions, one to create a list and one to check certain parameters within that list. The `check()` function is to see if any of the elements of the `price()` function's randomly generated list are >100 then inform the user which of those elements need to be recorded. To be honest, I'm not really sure where to begin with the `check()` function and was hoping someone might have some advice?

```
def price():
    priceList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    print ("Price of Item Sold:")
    for i in range (10):
        priceList[i] = random.uniform(1.0,1000.0)
        print("${:7.2f}".format(priceList[i]))
    print("\n")
    return priceList
```

I know the `check()` function is way off, but like I said, not exactly sure where to go with it.

```
def check(priceList):
    if priceList > 100
        print ("This item needs to be recorded")
```

Thank you in advanced for any help!

Comment: Do you need to check if all elements of `priceList` are less than 100? Or find which elements are great than 100?

Comment: `checkthese = [p for p in priceList if p > 100]`

Comment: There's no need to have any initial values in pricelist. You can change the first line of price() to `priceList = []`, since all the items will be replaced with random values anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the best way to go.

```
def price():
    priceList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    print ("Price of Item Sold:")
    for i in range (10):
        priceList[i] = random.uniform(1.0,1000.0)
        print("${:7.2f}".format(priceList[i]))
    print("\n")
    return priceList
```

And for checking the list.

```
def check(): #Will go through the list and print out any values greater than 100
    plist = price()
    for p in plist:
        if p > 100:
            print("{} needs to be recorded".format(p))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to loop over the values passed to the check function.

```
def check(priceList, maxprice=100):
    for price in priceList:
        if price > maxprice:
            print("{} is more than {}".format(price, maxprice)
            print ("This item needs to be recorded")
```

You can generate the pricelist with price() and pass it to check() at once, if you like.

```
check(price())
```